# iOS Background fetch for local notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have 8 medicine local notifications which differ from day to day.

They work fine for one day but I want to fire them everyday. I used BackgroundFetch to reschedule the local notifications every time fetch is executed. But my problem here is that background fetch depends on how often the user uses the app. What if the user doesn't open the app more often  Also I didn't want to implement silent notifications because it will not wake up the app if the user does not have internet connection. what approach should I use instead of background fetch?

**EDIT:**

I also thought about location updates in background because my notification times are taken from location of user and calculated accordingly. But will this consume a lot of battery?

Comment: I've got the same problem, I think that the only reliable solution is implement silent push notification that triggers the reschedule. OF course you need a PUSH service.

Comment: @Andrea it looks like that but the problem now resides in if no internet connection what to do?

Comment: @Andrea have you thought about fetching location updates or do you think it is not a good approach?

Comment: location updates consumes more battery, you should not rely on it until really necessary. silent push notification would be a nice extra way for reschedule. In the end you need to reconcile there's nothing more you can do and be a good citizen app

Comment: I think that the only solution is Mix of different approaches. Significant location monitoring updates can be a good alternative, it doesn't consume a lot of power but you can't be so sure about how many times will be called and about the time that the system gives you to perform an operation on background (it's a fake background). Furthermore the other problem is how to communicate the user that your app needs:location,notifications etc to do something that in his mind is a simple task

Comment: Do not forget also that user may disable both background fetch and location services for an app. So as push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've got the same issue in an 
app that probably does the same stuff as yours, I'd like to share my solution.
It comes with one compromise works only from >=iOS8.
By using an interactive notifications you can reschedule your notifications in background, of course the user need to interact with the notification, but I think that if you different actions instead of open the app or cancel the notification is possible to have more interested user.
It's all about creating a configuration with actions.
[Here](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/) you can find a tutorial.